# Multiple fragments with same method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have 5 fragments, where each fragment class has the exact same method:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // other methods

    public void clear() {
        data.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The second fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    // other methods

    public void clear() {
        data.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And so on...

How can I organize my code better so that I don't have to copy and paste this method into each of my 5 fragments (i.e. make one method, call the same method in each fragment).

Comment: You could make a static class with the method in and call it from each of the fragments. Answer provided by @Saurabh is better, Try that first

Comment: Lots of ways of doing this..  1) Create a base fragment with the method implementation and have all your fragments derive from it. 2) Create a static method and refer to it.

Comment: The basic idea behind the method is re-usability.
Create one static final method in one Utilities class..
When ever you want, just call that method using class name. So compiler will call this method in optimized way as it's final method..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the concept of [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)), put all the common variables and methods in a `BaseFragment` and extend others from it.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
public Data data;
public Adapter adapter;
        public void clear() {
            data.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

First:

```
public class FirstFragment extends BaseFragment {
    // other methods
}
```

Second:

```
public class SecondFragment extends BaseFragment {
    // other methods
}
```

Comment: You can also make the method `protected` since it's not necessary to be visible outside the class.